# Comandos de la funcion php shell exec

Tags: php, shell

me sale error en un sistema que intento migrar de ip, algun master en php que me pueda apoyar en que hacen cada uno de los comandos del shell_exec

$returnShell = shell_exec('SCHTASKS /CREATE /TN "'.$txtNameTask.'" /SC DAILY /ST '.date("H:i", strtotime($txtHourTask)).' /TR "C:\xampp\php\php.exe -f '.$nameRutaTask.' iniciar='.$txtNameIniTask.'" /RU REPOSITORIO2\credito /RP '.PASS_DIR.' /F');

//este error varias veces
Warning: Undefined array key 1 in F:\xampp\htdocs\AppCronJobs\php\funciones.php on line 247

//y este tambien, solo lo resumo
error {"response":true,"arrayTable":[{"nameTask":"\agent-recovery-task","timeDateLastTask":"11/17/2021 9:09:14 AM","timeDateNextTask":"N/A","days":"","stateTask":"Disabled","statusTask":"Ready"},{"nameTask":"\agent-recovery-task-periodic","timeDateLastTask":"11/23/2021 1:36:00 PM","timeDateNextTask":"11/23/2021 6:36:00 PM","days":"","stateTask":"Disabled","statusTask":"Ready"},{"nameTask":"\createexplorershellunelevatedtask","timeDateLastTask":"10/12/2021 1:41:26 PM","timeDateNextTask":"N/A","days":"","stateTask":"Disabled","statusTask":"Ready"},{"nameTask":"\googleupdatetaskmachinecore","timeDateLastTask":"11/23/2021 2:52:39 PM","timeDateNextTask":"11/24/2021 2:52:39 PM","days":"","stateTask":"Disabled","statusTask":"Ready"},{"nameTask":"\googleupdatetaskmachinecore","timeDateLastTask":"11/23/2021 2:52:39 PM","timeDateNextTask":"11/24/2021 2:52:39 PM","days":"","stateTask":"Disabled","statusTask":"Ready"},{"nameTask":"\googleupdatetaskmachineua","timeDateLastTask":"11/23/2021 5:52:39 PM","timeDateNextTask":"11/23/2021 6:52:39 PM","days":"","stateTask":"Disabled","statusTask":"Ready"},{"nameTask":"\user_feed_synchronization-{3d8c452c-a313-4640-ac6e-0ad53235aad9}","timeDateLastTask":"11/11/2021 1:51:12 PM","timeDateNextTask":"11/23/2021 8:17:05 PM","days":"","stateTask":"Disabled","statusTask":"Ready"},{"nameTask":"\user_feed_synchronization-{77177273-1649-43e8-a133-edc044fb3d3d}","timeDateLastTask":"11/23/2021 5:47:39 PM","timeDateNextTask":"11/24/2021 12:02:03 AM","days":"","stateTask":"Disabled","statusTask":"Ready"},{"nameTask":"\user_feed_synchronization-{7f31eac6-63b9-4a7f-a137-5fa24c264c08}","timeDateLastTask":"11/30/1999 12:00:00 AM","timeDateNextTask":"11/23/2021 7:20:44

Comment: Puedes añadir que error te da?

Comment: Listo @DavidFloresGarcía

Comment: Lo que quiero es que guarde en otra ruta diferente a la que me manda que es en el disco f de la ip a usar, carpeta xampp/php/php.exe, solo quiero una orientacion sobre que hacen esos comandos de la funcion shell_exec, ya que en la documentacion no encuentro info

Answer (score 0):

En términos simples la función `shell_exec` ejecuta un comando mediante el intérprete de comandos, imagina que escribieses una instrucción en una terminal.

> Mas información en
> https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.shell-exec.php

En cuanto al parámetro ingresado a la función es una función que asumiendo `$txtNameTask=NameTask` la hora de ejecución de la sentencia a las `10:36 AM`, `$nameRutaTask=/to/path/task` y `PASS_DIR=password` resultaría en algo así:

```sh
SCHTASKS /CREATE 
     /TN "NameTask"
     /SC DAILY 
     /ST "10:36" 
     /TR "C:\xampp\php\php.exe -f '/to/path/task' iniciar=NameTask"
     /RU REPOSITORIO2\credito 
     /RP password 
     /F
```

Que no es mas que una instrucción para la creación de una tarea programada en *Microsoft Windows*

> Mas información
> https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/schtasks-create